# how to disable inline disable comments for pylint and flake8?

Tags: python, pylint, flake8

we started using pylint and flake8. But, I see many just adding an inline comment to disable the pylint/flake8 error/warnings. Is there a way to ignore these inline comments and generate a complete report in pylint and flake8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
flake8 --disable-noqa
```

I don't know if pylint has something similar (and couldn't quickly find something).

*Not quite a solution*, but if it helps, you can at least make `pylint` issue a warning for locally disabled checks. Given `foo.py`:

```
def foo(l):  # noqa: E741 pylint: disable=invalid-name
    return l + 1
```

you can run:

```
pylint --enable locally-disabled foo.py
```

to get:

```
************* Module foo
foo.py:1:0: I0011: Locally disabling invalid-name (C0103) (locally-disabled)
foo.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)
foo.py:1:0: C0104: Disallowed name "foo" (disallowed-name)
foo.py:1:0: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
foo.py:1:0: C0104: Disallowed name "foo" (disallowed-name)
```

At least you can look for the locations with `I0011`.

Update: In a comment, @pierre-sassoulas wrote that "Enabling 'suppressed-message' is pylint official ways to disable noqas": https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/information/locally-disabled.html. Thank you, Pierre, for mentioning it.

Additionally, you might want to enable https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/information/file-ignored.html, informing when entire files are being skipped.

Comment: Enabling 'suppressed-message' is pylint official ways to disable noqas. https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/information/suppressed-message.html